# Invoke a web service form JQuery: doesn't work in IE (JQMIGRATE: jQuery.browser is deprecated ??)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

I'm a newbie in Ajax and JQuery but I need to invoke a web service in my little web application HTML/Javascript based.

All works fine using Firefox or Chrome  but nothing happens using IE (I'm using IE 9 now ...).

Here you are the code

```
if ($.browser.msie && window.XDomainRequest) {
            if (window.XDomainRequest) {
                var query = 'http://wms.pcn.minambiente.it/ogc?map=/ms_ogc/wfs/Numeri_Civici_2012.map&SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=1.0.0&REQUEST=GetFeature&TYPENAME=IN.NUMERICIVICI.2012&SRSNAME=EPSG:4326&bbox=7.70,44.80,7.75,44.85&outputFormat=GML2';
                var xdr = new XDomainRequest();
                if (xdr) {
                    xdr.onload = function () {
                        alert("OK");
                    }
                    xdr.onerror = function () { 
                        alert("KO");
                    }
                    xdr.open('GET', query);
                    xdr.send();
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            var query = 'http://wms.pcn.minambiente.it/ogc?map=/ms_ogc/wfs/Numeri_Civici_2012.map&SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=1.0.0&REQUEST=GetFeature&TYPENAME=IN.NUMERICIVICI.2012&SRSNAME=EPSG:4326&bbox=7.70,44.80,7.75,44.85&outputFormat=GML2';
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: query,
                dataType: "text",
                crossDomain: true,
                success: function (data1) {
                      alert("OK");
                      alert(data1)
                },
                error: function (response, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert("KO");
                    alert(errorThrown);
                }
            });
        }
```

I tried to [synthesize in a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CesareGerbino/4h75w59f/) so you can try if you want.

When I try to execute in IE the browser console tell me that ...

JQMIGRATE: jQuery.browser is deprecated

How can I modify my code?

Thank you all in advance, any suggestion or wokaround will be appreciated!!!

Cesare

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$.browser` function is, indeed, [deprecated](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/). If you want to detect IE, use this instead:

```
var browser = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase(),
isIE = (browser.indexOf("msie")>-1 || browser.indexOf("trident")>-1);
if (isIE && window.XDomainRequest) {
  //the rest of your code
}
```